# Calling main function from other class

Tags: android, class, global-variables, toast

I got this problem, I am struggling for few hours, what I thought it would take few minutes.
I tried many things, like using a thread and such, but I think this can be done much easier.

This is my decompress class (Unzipper):

```
    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Enumeration;
    import java.util.Observable;
    import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
    import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

    import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class Decompress extends Observable {

        static final String TAG = "UnZip";
        int counter;
        private String mFileName, mFilePath, mDestinationPath;

        public Decompress (String fileName, String filePath, String destinationPath) {
            mFileName = "bigflow";
            mFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            mDestinationPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/bigflow/";

        }

        public String getFileName () {
            return mFileName;
        }

        public String getFilePath() {
            return mFilePath;
        }

        public String getDestinationPath () {
            return mDestinationPath;
        }

        public void unzip () {
            System.out.println("unzipping...");
            String fullPath = mFilePath + "/" + mFileName + ".zip";
            Log.d(TAG, "unzipping " + mFileName + " to " + mDestinationPath);
            new UnZipTask().execute(fullPath, mDestinationPath);

        }

        private class UnZipTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
                String filePath = params[0];
                String destinationPath = params[1];

                File archive = new File(filePath);
                try {
                    ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(archive);
                    for (Enumeration e = zipfile.entries(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
                        ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
                        unzipEntry(zipfile, entry, destinationPath);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error while extracting file " + archive, e);
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers();
            }

            private void unzipEntry(ZipFile zipfile, ZipEntry entry,
                    String outputDir) throws IOException {

                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    createDir(new File(outputDir, entry.getName()));
                    return;
                }

                File outputFile = new File(outputDir, entry.getName());
                if (!outputFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
                    createDir(outputFile.getParentFile());
                }

                Log.v(TAG, "Extracting: " + entry);
                BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(zipfile.getInputStream(entry));
                BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

                try {
                    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
                } finally {
                    outputStream.close();
                    inputStream.close();
------------------->   counter++; <--------------------------------
                }

               } 

            private void createDir(File dir) {
                if (dir.exists()) {
                    return;
                }
                Log.v(TAG, "Creating dir " + dir.getName());
                if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Can not create dir " + dir);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

After `counter++;` I want to check if it is on 387 (or something else) then I want to show a message. But I can't that do that in this class, it needs to be done in the main class.
But somehow I can't get it happen.
Is it possible if `counter` == 387 that my program goes back to the `MainActivity()` and call an function?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
}
```

I know how to make toast and such, but it isn't working from the decompress class.
Any solution is welcome to show a message when counter is a certain number.

I hope you guys know what I mean, else say it, always can give more info.

Tried this:
`Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`
getBaseContext is undefined because decompress class isn't an Activity.

Logcat:

```
11-15 09:20:50.315: E/UnZip(6495): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
11-15 09:20:50.315: E/UnZip(6495):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
11-15 09:20:50.315: E/UnZip(6495):  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:317)
11-15 09:20:50.315: E/UnZip(6495):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
11-15 09:20:50.315: E/UnZip(6495):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:233)
11-15 09:20:50.315: E/UnZip(6495):  at com.bigflow.dark_legacy.MainActivity$1.message(MainActivity.java:45)
11-15 09:20:50.315: E/UnZip(6495):  at com.bigflow.dark_legacy.Decompress$UnZipTask.unzipEntry(Decompress.java:109)
11-15 09:20:50.315: E/UnZip(6495):  at com.bigflow.dark_legacy.Decompress$UnZipTask.doInBackground(Decompress.java:70)
11-15 09:20:50.315: E/UnZip(6495):  at com.bigflow.dark_legacy.Decompress$UnZipTask.doInBackground(Decompress.java:1)
11-15 09:20:50.315: E/UnZip(6495):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
11-15 09:20:50.315: E/UnZip(6495):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-15 09:20:50.315: E/UnZip(6495):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-15 09:20:50.315: E/UnZip(6495):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-15 09:20:50.315: E/UnZip(6495):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-15 09:20:50.315: E/UnZip(6495):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Why cant the toast be raised in the Decompress class?

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen See last few lines

Comment: why dont you just send the context as a parameter to the constructor? and use this context as the first parameter in the `Toast.makeText(..,..,..)`

Comment: You can use GetActivity to get the activity and then activity.Toast etc

Comment: Are you calling *Decompress* class from an *Activity* class. If yes, @TobiasMoeThorstensen's approach will definitely help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:
I mean, I was taking your word for it when you said you couldn't make a Toast message from Decompress (kinda lazy to read everything), but try sending in your Activities context as a parameter instead, and then invoke Toast in `onPostUpdate`.

Your best option in this case is to also send a listener in as a parameter in your constructor. So wherever in your Activity that you call`Decompress`:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/*Stuff and more stuff*/
    new Decompress (String fileName, String filePath, String destinationPath, 
    new MyListener(){
        public void message() { 
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    });
}
```

**Decompress class**:

```
public class Decompress extends Observable {

static final String TAG = "UnZip";
int counter;
private String mFileName, mFilePath, mDestinationPath;
MyListener listen;

public Decompress (String fileName, String filePath, String destinationPath, MyListener listener) {
    mFileName = "bigflow";
    mFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    mDestinationPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/bigflow/";
    listen = listener;
}
//......
```

And of course the actual interface defined somewhere

```
public interface MyListener{
    void message();
}
```

Oh and almost forgot

```
finally {
         outputStream.close();
         inputStream.close();
         counter++;
         if(counter == 387) listen.message();
         }
```

Not really sure if thats how you want it, or in that section, but you get the idea.

Cheers!

Comment: +1 for your approach. I havnt tried this, but seems to be a good one.

Comment: Thanks @SahilMahajanMj :) Yea, in this case since there is no relationship between Activity/CustomClass, this is the best way.

Comment: What can't you get to work? What is giving you an error? If you do it as is to be honest, it should not give you any errors.

Comment: @Andy The constructor Decompress(String, String, String, MyListener) refers to the missing type MyListener

Comment: Where are you putting the actual interface `MyListener` at? Just put it in a separate file and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Andy Thanks, got everything working, thanks to you ofcourse!